# Cron scheduler "disable pattern"

Tags: java, cron

I have application with configured cron tasks. Tasks scheduler config is separated to distinct file.
Could I use same crone scheduler config to enable or disable any task by providing specific pattern?

PS. I got different parse exceptions whet trying to use values like -1, 2000, 2810 for year in the pattern. It works for year 2080, but is there any common approach to be used here?

Thanks.

Comment: Any reason you can't just comment out the line(s) for the jobs you want to disable?

Comment: If comment out record in config Spring throws an exception like "Can't find property..." Your solution could be suitable in some cases but is not working in my case.

Comment: Ah. When asking this sort of question, it's usually helpful to include that sort of contextual information. Commenting out the line is the usual way of disabling cron jobs, which is why there is no typical cron metasyntax for indicating a disabled job. Could you post the relevant bit of your Spring config? May help someone see what can be done...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this cron scheduler expression to effectively disable it: 0 0 0 1 1 ? 2099

Comment: This one worked for me. I tried with year 2200 and above and I got the "will never run" error.

Comment: shouldn't year be set to any past years or some impossible dates like 30th February ? because that way the Job won't run until it is triggered manually/forcefully.